# Ansible automatically flips variable

Tags: ansible

I recently came across a very strange behavior of Ansible and would like to know why this is happening.

I'm using **Ansible 2.7.7** with **python 3.5.3**.

So to the point.
I have two variables:

```yaml
GLOBAL_HIGHEST_PARAM: "{5,0}"
LOCAL_HIGHEST_PARAM: "{5,0}"
```

And using `LOCAL_HIGHEST_PARAM` for example like this:

```yaml
- name: Setting up highest score param {{ LOCAL_HIGHEST_PARAM }}
  # ...
```

Which gives me the correct output during run: `Setting up highest score param {5,0}`

But when I define variables such as:

```yaml
GLOBAL_HIGHEST_PARAM: "{5,0}"
LOCAL_HIGHEST_PARAM: "{{ GLOBAL_HIGHEST_PARAM }}"
```

I get the incorrect output: `Setting up highest score param {0,5}`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `{5,0}` is actually a [Python set](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), which you can actually see debugging the variable:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ GLOBAL_HIGHEST_PARAM }}"
  vars:
    GLOBAL_HIGHEST_PARAM: "{5,0}"
```

Would yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: !!set
    0: null
    5: null
```

And since `5` and `0` are the keys of the set, the set get sorted by keys.

You can force it to be represented as a string, though, with the [`string`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.string) filter of Jinja.

The task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ LOCAL_HIGHEST_PARAM }}"
  vars:
    GLOBAL_HIGHEST_PARAM: "{5,0}"
    LOCAL_HIGHEST_PARAM: "{{ GLOBAL_HIGHEST_PARAM | string }}"
```

Will give you the expected

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: '{5,0}'
```

---

Note that it does work in a task name because tasks names can only be string, so it is implicitly casted as a string, while it might not be, in other cases, without an explicit `string` filter.